# Is there a distinction similar to the one between “question” and “query” in French?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, synonymes

In English there are two nouns, *question* and *query*, which appear to be very similar in meaning but that, if looked at cautiously reveal themselves a bit different from each other. In the context of a course or in a meeting saying "Any Questions?" and "Any Queries?" amount to the same thing. But, in a multiple choice test we employ "questions", not "queries". On the other hand in a database we see the term "queries", not "questions". Roughly, "query" is used in the context of a need of clarifying a doubt, expressing a doubt or getting information about something. "Question" is used to get an answer or a discussion over the question.

In French both of these words are always conveyed by (la) question? Is there any other word that conveys this nuance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often heard after exposing some matters in front of a class:

> Questions ? Commentaires ? Discussions ?

It is an invitation to ask questions, requests details, expose your comprehension when you doubt you understood everything, etc.

It would be used in pretty much the same context as your *“Any questions? Any queries?”*.

---

I am not overly familiar with databases, especially in French, but I believe the English *query* is usually translated as *requête*...

Answer (score 3):

Just for adding informations about the database part. In France, we are used to say :

> Le programme **interroge/questionne** la base de données.

Or

> Le programme **lance/envoie/fait/crée une requête** à la base de données.

*Even if the verb "to request" exists in French, it is never used in this context.*

Both above solutions are commonly used. The first one will be used when you want to say that your program query the database (global behavior of your program). The second one is more focused on the query itself.

Comment: I never heard *(il) questionne la base de données* but ont the other hand I definitely heard and used *(il) requête une base de donnée*.

Comment: I think, it depends on the teacher you had.

Comment: I was basing this comment on my professional experience but I have indeed found "*questionner la base données*" occurrences on the web. Some of them are from French Canadian so it might be more popular there. By the way, you ignored my comment about *litotes* on your *il s'est pas foutu de toi* reply.

Answer (score 2):

There are the words *question*, *requête* and *demande* in French.

[**Question**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/question#Nom_commun) is when you ask for information, about something you don't know.

[**Requête**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/requ%C3%AAte#Nom_commun) is used in administrative or legal context, when you ask for something to be done (instead of asking for information). It can also be a formal way to ask something to do from somone.
It is also used for databases as the translation of *query*.

[**Demande**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/demande#Nom_commun) is more or less the same as *requête* but is less formal, it is also less authoritarian because *requête* can be used for conflicts (and yet be less authoritarian than a *demand*) while *demande[Fr]* would be used for negociation or a genuine request.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description (*"query" is used in the context of a need of clarifying a doubt, expressing a doubt or getting information about something*), a query might be ***une interrogation*** (doubt) or ***une demande*** (getting information about something) while "**question**" would keep the same meaning in both languages.

You might then ask after a meeting:

> Des questions ? des interrogations ?